# Excel 2013: copy the row for the number of computers in that room

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, excel-2013

I have a worksheet in my workbook that has the number of computers by room that I want to copy the row for the number of computers in that room.  I have several rooms that I need to do this for.

Example:

```
Room    Count   Model     Year
201      24      MBP      2015
```

Result after Macro has run

```
Room    Unit    Model     Year     Serial
201      1       MBP      2015      001
201      2       MBP      2015      002
201      3       MBP      2015      003
201      4       MBP      2015      004
201      5       MBP      2015      005
```

Once the count of systems in room 201 reaches zero I want to move to room 202 and do the same at the bottom of the data block for room 201 and so on.

Is there a way to do this using VBA macros in Excel versus typing it all out or copy and paste?

Thank you for the help - I could not make sense of the code snippets I have read on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code assumes source data is in `ActiveSheet` range `A1:D19` and we post the output list in same worksheet starting at cell `F1` *(change as needed)*

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub ListRoomComputers()
Const kCol As Byte = 6  'Column F

Dim aOutput() As Variant
aOutput = Array("Room", "Unit", "Model", "Year", "Serial")

Dim rDta As Range, rRow As Range
Dim lCnt As Long, lUnit As Long
Dim lRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet

        Rem Set Data Ranges
        Set rDta = .Range("A2:D19")

        Rem Generate Room\Unit\Serial Data
        lRow = 1
        .Cells(lRow, kCol).Resize(, 5).Value = aOutput

        For Each rRow In rDta.Rows

            Rem Get Room Data
            With WorksheetFunction
                aOutput = .Transpose(.Transpose(rRow.Value2))
            End With
            ReDim Preserve aOutput(5)
            lCnt = aOutput(2)

            Rem Fill Room\Unit\Serial Data
            For lUnit = 1 To lCnt
                lRow = 1 + lRow                     'Increase Row Number
                aOutput(2) = lUnit                  'Unit
                aOutput(5) = Format(lUnit, "'000")  'Serial
                .Cells(lRow, kCol).Resize(, 5).Value = aOutput

    Next: Next: End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

say you have that in sheet1 and i am going to paste out in sheet2

```
Option Explicit
Sub print_list()
 Dim idx As Integer, ptr As String, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, row2 As Integer, c As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Set ws1 = Application.Worksheets(1)
Set ws2 = Application.Worksheets(2)
ws2.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Room"
ws2.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Unit"
ws2.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Model"
ws2.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Year"
ws2.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Serial"
row2 = 2
idx = 2
ws2.Columns(5).NumberFormat = "@"
Do
  ptr = ws1.Cells(idx, 2).Value
  ptr = Trim(ptr)
  If ptr = "" Then Exit Do
  c = CInt(ptr)
  For i = 1 To c
    ws2.Cells(row2, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(idx, 1).Value
    ws2.Cells(row2, 2).Value = i
    ws2.Cells(row2, 3).Value = ws1.Cells(idx, 3).Value
    ws2.Cells(row2, 4).Value = ws1.Cells(idx, 4).Value
    ws2.Cells(row2, 5).Value = Format(i, "00#")
    row2 = row2 + 1
  Next
 idx = idx + 1
Loop While True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over each row in the source worksheet, loop per the number of machines in the row, and add a new row to the destination worksheet within the loop with the values from the row.

(NB. I personally would use SQL statements for this)